# How to add acceleration to velocity?

Tags: python

I have an image called arrow. I want to shoot arrows when I press spacebar. I did it by calculating `velx` and `vely` by using an angle I already have.

```
velx = math.cos(angle)*10
vely = math.sin(angle)*10
```

I added `velx` to the x-coordinate of my image and `vely` to y-coordinate of my image and I'm able to shoot arrows.

Now, I want to accelerate `vely` by `-9.8` . How do I do it?

Comment: A general formula for the velocity under a constant acceleration is v(t) = v0 + a * t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh hey, classic 2D game physics! Let's consider everything is in
meters and seconds, as that's what your gravitational constant `-9.8`
looks like.

So you have your position (in meters),

```
posx = 0
posy = 0
```

your velocity (in m/s), which has been already instantaneously
accelerated to what it is now (i.e. the archer's arm has applied 10 m/s of velocity to the arrow),

```
velx = math.cos(angle) * 10
vely = math.sin(angle) * 10
```

your gravity (in m/s^2),

```
gravx = 0
gravy = -9.8
```

so now in your physics simulation loop, for each frame all you need to do is

```
timestep = 0.1  # seconds to simulate this frame; this depends on FPS, etc.

# move the object according to its velocity
posx += velx * timestep
posy += vely * timestep

# apply acceleration based on gravity (you could add wind, etc. here)
velx += gravx * timestep
vely += gravy * timestep
```

You can find the same sort of simulation here in Khan Academy's
astounding [Pixar in a Box series](https://www.khanacademy.org/partner-content/pixar/simulation/hair-simulation-code/p/step-1-particle-under-gravity).